# Capacitors under rapid current change

Tags: capacitor

Three capacitors (of value 600uF) are connected in series together and connected to an AC voltage source. Capacitors will be damaged if they are subjected to any fast changes in the current passing through them (i.e., they are sensitive to high di/dt). How can the capacitors be protected versus the fast changes in the current passing through them?

I think, adding an inductor to the circuit solves this problem? But how it is going to solve it? I am not quite sure. Can anyone out there help me in this? Many thanks.

Comment: Easiest and simplest is adding a resistor in series with the capacitors

Comment: What kind of capacitors are *damaged* by high di/dt, as opposed to simply high peak current?

Comment: An inductor is a good choice, a resistor may also work depending on the application. To find the size of inductor to use max di/dt = v/L and solve for L. I believe this kind of thing is called a snubber.

Comment: @THEMuffinMan7 Very helpful answer! Thanks

Comment: Such capacitors would have to be *non-polarized* electrolytic. What precautions (e.g., bleeder resistors) did you take to make sure the AC voltage was distributed equally across them?

Answer (score 2):

First, your premise is wrong. Capacitors eat di/dt for lunch. The current into the a capacitor is proportional to dv/dt, though, so high dv/dt might result in destructive current.

An AC waveform that is continuous like a triangle wave or sine wave has a bounded dv/dt, so (if that limitation is true) the current through the capacitors is also bounded when they are connected.

There is, however, something to worry about when the switch is closed connecting the capacitors to the AC voltage. Since this looks like homework, I think that is enough of a hint you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Yea, I have had 600V caps catch on fire when a switch was closed. They will act as a momentary short during the switch close, due to the dv/dt

Answer (score 0):

The series resistance and RMS current or voltage determines the loss factor in the otherwise reactive current. In very large film caps they are rated in VARs for a given line voltage.

Capacitors in high voltage class are either rated for ripple current (eg motor caps) or low ESR or both.  From these specs,,you can determine if there is going to be a thermal issue.

The dielectrics in this voltage and size are either electrolytic or plastic film, but for this AC application, one should choose film which have inherently low ESR and of course are bipolar.

Have you considered caps like these rated for 800V and around 60 Amps? What is your application?
http://www.cde.com/catalogs/947C.pdf